# FFMPEG - Strange issue with video copy

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I'm new here.

I have a set of TIF frames that equal 1 minute and 25 seconds of a video.

I'm attempting to copy the frames without re-encoding using the "-c:v copy" function to avoid visible quality loss for a process I'm doing on my side. The command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -r 23.977 -i %06d.tif -c:v copy out.mkv
```

However for some reason, the timing does not seem to be accurate and the video is slightly desynced from the original, ending at 1 minute and 22 seconds instead.

When I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 23.977 -i %06d.tif out.mkv
```

It comes out with the proper timing at 1 minute and 25 seconds, however, I did not appreciate the quality loss that came with it.

Is there a workaround to this or is there something I'm missing?

I used both Command Line and Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it would make sense to transcode when you go from tiff to video format. (I'm surprised it actually works.) You can set encoding quality to your own liking. See [this FFmpeg Wiki article[(https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Ah I see. This works perfectly fine. Thank you.